# how to do we know which message is for which service in rabbitmq

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq

when two services are listening to the same queues how can we make them distinguish it?we have a queue lets name it CalculateMyCost,two different services are using this queue ,how the receiver should distinguish the request is coming from which service?

Answer (score 1):

If two services are *consuming* from the same queue, one message will get to only one of them.

I think you might want to change your design to:

- single exchange,
- two queues, each with its unique routing key bound to the exchange,
- producer produces message with RK matching the intended consumer.

You might also investigate fanout exchanges and message headers - however that would mean every message would get delivered to every queue.